# how to set value of CheckBox to true in viewModel?

Tags: xamarin.forms

i want one checkbox to be by default checked. I have tried this but its not working. I have tried to set IsChecked true in xaml but then it doesnt get affected.

```
public bool FilterAlphabetically
        {
            set
            {
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                _filterAlphabetically = value;
 _filterAlphabetically = true;

                if (FilterAlphabetically)
                {
                    UserDecision.Add(1);
                    FilterNotListened = false;
                }
            }
            get => _filterAlphabetically;
        }
```

Comment: is your checkbox bound to this property?  Are you using INotifyPropertyChanged?  Are you initializing the value to true?  bools will default to false.

Comment: You might want to call the `NotifyPropertyChanged();` method at last, at least once you have set the new value.

Comment: ok well but how do i set it to true as default

Comment: "its not working" tells us little. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Comment: @theTinMan i already found a solution that is posted and accepted below, sorry i didnt respond to your comment. Bu that i ment the checkbox is not checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to bind `IsChecked` to your property:

```
<CheckBox ... IsChecked="{Binding FilterAlphabetically}" ... />
```

and be sure to set the default value to true:

```
// bools are false by default
public bool FilterAlphabetically { ... } = true;
```

Comment: yes i have    IsChecked="{Binding FilterAlphabetically, Mode=TwoWay}" and if i set it to true in VM then is not checked. I am using INotify

Comment: where do i intialize it? All i have is what i posted plus    private bool _filterAlphabetically;

Comment: you can initialize it like I show in my answer, or just set the private _filterAlphabetically to true when you declare it

Comment: thank you, i set the private to true